# How to activate guard dog after kill streak?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

How does the dog get activated after getting kill streak?

Answer (score 2):

After earning the guard dog killstreak, you can activate it by pressing the same button you press to activate any killstreak. On the Xbox and Playstation, press the right arrow on the directional pad. After that, the dog will appear at your side an attack enemies who come near you.

Source:
Personal experience playing many call of duty games.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a 5 kill streak to activate the dog when you have the required amount press right on the arrow pad. The dog will kill enemies if they get to close and will growl if it senses a enemy player in the visinity